# Vue JS (router.beforeEach) failed to convert exception to string

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm trying to use `router.beforeEach` with `localStorage`. If there is data in `localStorage`, I want to skip the homepage. If there is no data, enter the homepage. I can print the data with `console.log`, but the router process fails

> [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation > failed to
>   convert exception to string.

How do I control the navigation?

**My `router.js`:**

```
Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            name: 'index',
            components: {
                default: Index,
                header: MainNavbar
            },
            props: {
                header: {
                    colorOnScroll: 400
                }
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/landing',
            name: 'landing',
            components: {
                default: Landing,
                header: MainNavbar,
                footer: MainFooter
            },
            props: {
                header: {
                    colorOnScroll: 400
                },
                footer: {
                    backgroundColor: 'black'
                }
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            components: {
                default: Login,
                header: MainNavbar
            },
            props: {
                header: {
                    colorOnScroll: 400
                }
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/profile',
            name: 'profile',
            components: {
                default: Profile,
                header: MainNavbar,
                footer: MainFooter
            },
            props: {
                header: {
                    colorOnScroll: 400
                },
                footer: {
                    backgroundColor: 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    scrollBehavior: to => {
        if (to.hash) {
            return {
                selector: to.hash
            };
        } else {
            return {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            };
        }
    }
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    let adres = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adres'));
    if (!adres) {
        next('/');
    } else {
        next('/login');
    }
});

export default router;
```

**Example localdata:**

```
{  
   "id":1,
   "adi":"Demo",
   "soyadi":"Sef",
   "telefon":"05322375277",
   "adres":"Girne Mahallesi 6022 Sk. No:22 Kahta/Adıyaman",
   "fotograf":"http://localhost:8000/media/kullanici/sef/demosef/chef-1.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating an infinite loop where your `beforeEach` guard gets triggered over and over. In the `beforeEach` it checks whether there is an address in localStorage and redirects to either `/` or `/login`. Then again before you enter the new route `beforeEach` is called and checks if there is an address and redirects. The process is repeated ad infinitum. You need to call `next()` without any parameters somewhere in your `beforeEach` guard to confirm normal navigation. So you might want to do something like this ..

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.path == '/') {  // If we are entering the homepage.
    let adres = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adres'));
    if (!adres) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/login');
    }
  } else {  // Not entering the homepage. Proceed as normal.
    next()
  }
});
```